# Unable to Fetch_Assoc() of Prepared Statement in PHP, If Fetch is Used num_rows becomes Zero

Tags: php, prepared-statement

```
public function Login($username, $pass){
    if(!empty($username) && !empty($pass)){
        $user = $this->link->prepare("SELECT username, pass FROM users WHERE username=? AND pass=?");
        $user->bind_param("ss", $username, $pass);
        $user->execute();

        $row=$user->fetch_assoc();

        If($user->num_rows==1){         
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['name']=$row['username'];
            $_SESSION['name']=true;
            header("Location: admin.php");                  
        }else{
            echo "Invalid Username and Password";   
        }   

    }else{
        echo "Empty Login Details";
    }
}
```

The Test for `num_row = 0` because the result is now in associate array,
When i used `Fetch()`, the `num_rows` was correct to be 1, but i can not access the array to assign `$row['username']` to Session Variable.

Comment: Just move `$row=$user->fetch_assoc();` into the if-block after the test on `$user->num_rows`

Comment: Note, if you already have the data, then asking mysqli for the data count is pointless, just test/count the data you already have!

Comment: @Nick i have Moved  $row=$user->fetch_assoc(); into the if block, yet test count $user->num_rows==1 is still False

Comment: @Fjay have you tried printing the value of `$user->num_rows`? Perhaps it is greater than 1...

Comment: @Nick, Yes, the Value is 0 instead of One

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue is you are not getting the result, I mean you're missing [mysqli_stmt::get_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php).

Your code is supposed to be

```
$user->bind_param("ss", $username, $pass);
$user->execute();
$result = $user->get_result();

if($result->num_rows === 1){
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc()
    $_SESSION['name']=$row['username'];
    header("Location: admin.php");
}else{
    echo "Invalid Username and Password";   
}
```

Why fetching if no rows are returned right?

And you are overriding the session here

```
$_SESSION['name']=$row['username'];
$_SESSION['name']=true;
```

The last session `$_SESSION['name']` is overriding the first one.

Comment: Should have been a comment, But Okay.

Comment: Thanks, The Second Session is removed, the Problem,of $user->num_rows==1 persist

Comment: Hey @Fjay a new answer is waiting for you.

Comment: @Saral, Thanks a Million, It Worked!!